Error Handling in Oracle EBS R12 PL/SQL Procedure: ORA-29283 - Invalid File Operation: Nonexistent File or Path [29434]
I have created 2 concurrent programs: one responsible for generating PDF output using XDODTEXE executable, RTF template, and XML data definition. The other one executes the first concurrent program, then copies the PDF file from the APPLOUT directory to the PEDIDOS directory. Finally, it should send an email.
This my prc:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORTS_DETAILS(
    ERRBUF                  OUT VARCHAR2,
    RETCODE                 OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_ORG_ID                IN NUMBER,
    P_USER_ID               IN NUMBER,
    P_RESP_ID               IN NUMBER,
    P_RESP_APPL_ID          IN NUMBER
) AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
--
    v_request_id            NUMBER;
    v_layout                BOOLEAN;
    l_phase                 VARCHAR2(100);
    l_status                VARCHAR2(100);
    l_dev_phase             VARCHAR2(100);
    l_dev_status            VARCHAR2(100);
    l_messase               VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_smts                  VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_wait_for_request      BOOLEAN;
    v_newfile               VARCHAR2(100);
    v_oldfile               VARCHAR2(100);
    vfecha1                 VARCHAR2(50) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    P_html                  VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_correos               VARCHAR2(32767);
    p_text                  VARCHAR2(1000);
    p_subjects              VARCHAR2(2000);
    p_to                    VARCHAR2(2000) := 'micorreo@micorreo.com'; -- Cambia el correo aquí
    l_error                 VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
    v_numero_linea          VARCHAR2(50);
--

CURSOR cEmails IS
    SELECT 'micorreo@micorreo.com' email
    FROM DUAL;

BEGIN
    -- Configuración de NLS
    l_smts := 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= ''' || 'AMERICAN' || ''' NLS_TERRITORY= ''' || 'AMERICA' || ''' NLS_CURRENCY= ''' || '$' || '''' ||
              ' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY= ''' || 'AMERICA' || ''' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''' || '.,' || '''' ||
              ' NLS_CALENDAR= ''' || 'GREGORIAN' || ''' NLS_DATE_FORMAT= ''' || 'DD-MON-RR' || '''' ||
              ' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= ''' || 'AMERICAN' || ''' NLS_SORT= ''' || 'BINARY' || '''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_smts;

    -- Inicialización de variables EBS
    mo_global.init('AR'); 
    fnd_global.apps_initialize(user_id      => P_USER_ID,
                               resp_id      => P_RESP_ID,
                               resp_appl_id => P_RESP_APPL_ID);

    mo_global.set_policy_context('S', P_ORG_ID);
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info(P_ORG_ID);
    apps.fnd_profile.put('ORG_ID', P_ORG_ID);

    -- Reporte XML Publisher
    v_layout := FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT(template_appl_name => '',
                                       template_code      => '',
                                       template_language  => '',
                                       template_territory => '',
                                       output_format      => 'PDF');

    IF v_layout THEN
        v_request_id := apps.FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST
        (application     => '',
         program         => '',
         start_time      => NULL,
         sub_request     => FALSE,
         argument1       => p_org_id,
         argument2       => NULL,
         argument3       => NULL,
         argument4       => NULL,
         argument5       => NULL,
         argument6       => p_id_cliente,
         argument7       => '2024/02/01 00:00:00',
         argument8       => '2024/02/01 00:00:00'
        );

        COMMIT;

        IF v_request_id <> 0 THEN
            l_wait_for_request := apps.fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request(request_id => v_request_id,
                                                                       interval   => 20,
                                                                       max_wait   => 0,
                                                                       phase      => l_phase,
                                                                       status     => l_status,
                                                                       dev_phase  => l_dev_phase,
                                                                       dev_status => l_dev_status,
                                                                       message    => l_messase);

            COMMIT;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output, '== CREACIÓN DEL ARCHIVO EN APPLOUT ==');

    -- Envío de reporte por correo
    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output, '== MOVER ARCHIVOS A CARPETAS ==');

    v_newfile := 'Report___Detalle_de_Movim_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDMONYYYY') || '.pdf';
    v_oldfile := 'XXReport___Detalle_de_Movim_' || v_request_id || '_1.pdf';

    BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.FCOPY ('APPLOUT', v_oldfile, 'PEDIDOS', v_newfile); 
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_path THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Path al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_path: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_mode THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Mode al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_mode: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_operation THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Operation al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_operation: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_filehandle THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Filehandle al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_filehandle: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.read_error THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Read al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error read_error: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Exception no controlada al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||'- Error Others : ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    FOR c IN cEmails LOOP
        BEGIN
            IF l_correos IS NULL THEN
                l_correos := 'micorreo@micorreo.com';
            ELSE
                l_correos := l_correos || ';' || c.email;
            END IF;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.output,'== ENVIO DE CORREOS ==');
    -- EMAIL
    p_text := 'Detalle de movimientos ' || vfecha1;
    p_subjects := 'Detalle de movimientos ' || vfecha1;

    P_html := '<html><head></head><body> Saludos Cordiales,<br>' || CHR (13);
    P_html := P_html || '<p>Se Adjunta Detalle de movimientos al  '|| vfecha1|| '</p>'|| CHR (13);
    P_html := P_html || '<br></br>' || CHR (13);
    l_correos := NULL;

    fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.output,'== COMIENZA ITERACION ==');

    P_html := P_html || '<br><br><br>Atentamente,<br><br><br><br><b><i>Este correo es generado automaticamente, favor no responder.</i></b> </body></html>' || CHR (13);
    P_html := P_html || ' ';

    BEGIN
        pits_send_mail.send_email (p_directory     => 'PEDIDOS'
                                   p_sender        => p_to,
                                   p_recipient     => 'micorreo@micorreo.com',
                                   p_cc            => NULL,
                                   p_bcc           => NULL,
                                   p_subject       => p_subjects,
                                   p_body          => P_html,
                                   p_attachment1   => v_newfile,
                                   p_attachment2   => NULL,
                                   p_attachment3   => NULL,
                                   p_attachment4   => NULL,
                                   p_error         => l_error);

        apps.fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG, 'l_error - ' || l_error);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            Fnd_file.Put_line(Fnd_file.LOG,'Exception no controlada Email - ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    COMMIT;

    P_html := NULL;

    apps.fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'===================================================================================');
END REPORTS_DETAILS;

How to obtain the parameters of FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT?
How to obtain mo_global.init?
Is there a query? Because to obtain that data I rely on the screen of my first concurrent that generates the PDF output.
How to obtain FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT?
FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST Generates PDF output, the problem lies in copying the file and sending as an attachment.
I have validated the file name in the APPLOUT directory and it is correct and the source and destination directories exist in Oracle.
I have validated my user's permissions and it has active execution, reading, writing permissions.
I did tests changing the data of my stored procedure with the data of other concurrent procedures and the output is successful. So the problem lies in how the parameters of FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT, mo_global.init are obtained.

Your approach with a plsql program like this cannot work if your company has separate database and application/concurrent processing servers, which they should have.
The plsql code is running as a process on the database node and that process or utl_file only has access to the directories on the DB node, not on the application server ($APPLCSF/$APPLOUT).
To do such output file distribution, you would need to use a process that runs on the application server instead, for example of execution method Host or Java Concurrent Program.
We do something very similar with Blitz Report, using a Host concurrent program as it performs better than Java. You can download and study it as an example or contact me if you need help.
Regards, Andy
